# after installing nginx with vagrant/chef-solo, vagrant reload is required for it to run

Tags: nginx, vagrant

I'm using the following Vagrantfile to install nginx.  After I run vagrant up, a request to `http://192.168.33.14/` returns a 404 from nginx.  After I run 'vagrant reload', making a request to `http://192.168.33.14/` returns the expected proxied result.

I expect that the proxy works as expected after vagrant up.  I am writing the config change after running the nginx cookbook, so I suspect I need to reload nginx after writing the config file.  I tried a shell provisioner running `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload`, this fails with `nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "opscode-ubuntu-14.04"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_ubuntu-14.04_chef-provisionerless.box"

    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'set nocp' > /home/vagrant/.vimrc"

    config.vm.define "nginx" do |nginx|

        nginx.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.14"

        nginx.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
            chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
            chef.add_recipe "nginx"

            chef.json = {
                :nginx => {
                    dir: '/etc/nginx'  # this is the default value, sample only
                }
            }
        end

        nginx.vm.provision "shell",
            inline: "echo -e $1 > /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf",
            args: [<<-EOS
                server {
                    listen *:80;

                    location ~ ^/ {
                        proxy_pass http://192.168.33.11:8080;
                    }
                }
            EOS
            ]
    end
```

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: i think you should try this cookbook http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx and when start or stop nginx service, try the command as: service nginx start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem, also using Ubuntu 14.04 as the base box.

This post helped me:
http://www.rollnorocks.com/2014/05/fear-and-loathing-with-chef-and-nginx/

In short, the PID location for the initial install is different to what's set in the config. The chef recipe sets the config PID (default /var/run/nginx.pid), but the initial install uses the default Ubuntu setting (/run/nginx.pid).

A quick way of resolving this problem is adding this line to an attribute file:
override['nginx']['pid'] = '/run/nginx.pid'

This means the chef PID location is set to the same location that Ubuntu uses on the initial install.

A better fix would be to improve the recipe so the initial install uses a PID as set by chef - I can't find where to add that, so for now I'm using the quick fix above.

Answer (score 0):

Another work-around was found, setting install_method to source:

```
vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "nginx"

    chef.json = {
        :nginx => {
            install_method: "source"
        }
    }
end
```

I found the workaround here: https://github.com/miketheman/nginx/pull/223